# How to convert multiple lists with tuples into a dictionary with my code?

Tags: python

```
taggedwords=[]
for sentence in range(0,len(wordlist)):
    tagged = tagger.tag(wordlist[sentence])
    print(tagged)
```

The output is multiple lists of tuples. The only way I can convert all of them is by doing

```
dict(tagger.tag(wordlist[sentence]))
```

However, this would only convert one list into a dictionary. Is there a way to do all 104 of them at the same time?

Comment: I assume `wordlist` is a list of words (e.g. `['one', 'two', 'three']`), but what is `tagger`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one big dictionary than you could do:

```
bigdict = {}
for sentence in range(0,len(wordlist)):
    tagged = tagger.tag(wordlist[sentence])
    bigdict = {**bigdict, **dict(tagged)}
```

If you want a list where each element is a dictionary, then

```
dicts = []
for sentence in range(0,len(wordlist)):
    tagged = tagger.tag(wordlist[sentence])
    dicts.append(dict(tagged))
```

Comment: No problem - accept the answer to show appreciation!

Answer (score 0):

You might simply use `update` method of a dictionary. It takes a sequence of tuples and adds them efficiently to the dictionary. Like this:

```
all_tagged = {}
for sentence in wordlist:
    tagged = tagger.tag(sentence)
    all_tagged.update(tagged)
```

Note 1: I also simplified your for-loop. There's no need to iterate over range and then index `wordlist`. You can simply iterate over elements of `wordlist`! :)

Note 2: This solution is slightly faster than Joe's since it updates the dictionary, not overwrites an existing one.

---

Also: wouldn't `sentence_list` be a better name than `wordlist`?